# Help with simple SOQL relationship queries that I cant get to work

Tags: soql

Trying to understand relationship queries. Could you please review the quesries that wont work below and comment on what I am doing incorrectly?

I have 2 objects:
`Festivals__c` (Parent Object to Attendee)
`Attendee` object has two lookup fields Account & Festivals (name of festival)

These wont work

(Trying to query Attendee Name, Tickets purchased and Festival Name (Master-Detail); going from child to parent)

```
**SELECT Name,Tickets_Purchased__c,Festivals__r.Name FROM Attendee__c**
```

(Trying to Query  festival Name and attendee name - going from parent to child)

```
**SELECT Festivals__c.Name, (SELECT Name FROM Attendee__C) FROM Festivals__c**
```

(Trying to Query Attendee Name, tickets purchased and lookup Account)

```
 **SELECT Name,Tickets_Purchased__c,Account.Name FROM Attendee__c**
```

These statements work:

```
SELECT First_Name__c,Tickets_Purchased__c  FROM Attendee__c

 SELECT Festivals__c.Name FROM Festivals__c

 SELECT Name FROM Attendee__C
```

Sample Error Messages:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Festivals__r' in field path.
>
> Didn't understand relationship 'Attendee__C'
>
> Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field path

Comment: Without understanding the object model, I'd suggest you build your queries via the [developer workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench), which may help you through this quickly.

Comment: In your second example, try using a lower-case 'c' for 'Attendee__c'.
In your third example, since the Attendee__c is a custom object, all its relationships will be custom as well, so it can't be straight 'Account.Name'. Maybe 'Account__r.Name', but look at the lookup field definition on the object to be sure. Similarly for your 'Festivals__r' lookup issue from the first example. While Salesforce will suggest a relationship name, it can be overridden during the creation of the relationship field.

Comment: How can I lookup field definition on object like you suggest for a child to parent relationship? For parent to child I could locate the child relationship field name (typically plural_r)?

Answer (score 1):

Your queries look correct (at least the format of them) at first glance......

To get the correct relationship name for the **Parent to Child Query** navigate to:

Setup -> Develop -> Custom Object

1. Click on the object Name for the **CHILD** object
2. Find the Master Relationship Field and click on it
3. Look at the **Child Relationship Name**

ex.

[image]

In this case the query from Parent to Child would be:

```
Select ID, (Select ID From GetFeedback_Survey_Answers__r) From GetFeedback_Survey_Result__c
```

For a query from **Child to Parent** you would simply uses the Name of the Master Relationship Field....

In the above case, using the same steps 1-2 but looking at **API Name**

[image]

The query would be

```
Select ID, GetFeedback_Survey_Result__r.Name From GetFeedback_Survey_Answer__c
```